# TDD with Ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Can web application be developed in rails with TDD approach using Junit? or what other approcach we can follow in rails for TDD? Kindly suggest me? What about Cucumber and rspec?

Answer (score 1):

The current canonical way would be to use rspec. For feature requests, use rspec with capybara. You can look at the spec directory here https://github.com/mhartl/sample_app for a very popular example. MiniTest is also popular.